# Terminology question for poset maps

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, order-theory, posets

Is there a standard name for order-preserving maps $f\colon P\to Q$ of posets with the property that the image of a lower set is a lower set, or equivalently if $q\leq f(p)$ then there exists $p'\leq p$ with $f(p')=q$?

If you view the poset as a category, then this condition says that the functor associated to $P$ is surjective on in-stars.

In my research I need to consider the category of posets with these kinds of morphisms and I would like to know their name.  For example, if $P$ and $Q$ are face posets of regular CW complexes, then this property says that the image of each closed cell is a closed cell.

Comment: You don't also insist that the map is order-preserving?

Comment: By maps of posets I meant order preserving. I'll edit.

Comment: I suppose it could also be ambiguous whether one means $p\leq q\iff f(p)\leq f(q)$, or $p\leq q\to f(p)\leq f(q)$ or $p\lt q\to f(p)\lt f(q)$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, by order preserving I mean $a\leq b$ implies $f(a)\leq f(b)$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Is it possible for you to be more specific about your posets? For instance, finite sups and infs exist for face posets of regular CW complexes but not in general. I suspect that if your posets have semilattice structure, then you might have a morphism of semilattices, in which case another possible avenue is "limit preserving maps". In general, I don't think there is a standard name.

Comment: Infs and sups need not exist in my context nor be preserved.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg it seems as though you want something at least related to residuated mappings, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_mapping which are $f:P \to Q$ for which the pre-images of down sets are down sets. I can't find a "dual" notion in the literature which does this in the forward direction.

Comment: This "feels" like a topological condition, like a subbase maps to a subbase, a sort of subopen map.  Have you considered this perspective?

Comment: @The Masked Avenger. Now that you mentioned it, it is actually a topological condition. If we give posets the topology where the lower sets are precisely the open sets, then the order preserving maps are precisely the continuous functions, and the open maps are precisely the maps that map lower sets to lower sets. Similarly, if we give each poset the topology where the lower sets are precisely the closed sets, then the closed maps are precisely the maps that map lower sets to lower sets.

Comment: Yes it is the open maps for the Alexandrov topology but I want to know if poset people have a name.

Comment: If I were developing the subject (and if I could remember whether down sets were called filters or ideals, let's say filters), then I would call such maps filter maps.  I am not a poset person and currently don't talk in a knowing way to poset people, so consider this an opinion.

Comment: Down sets are called ideals. Furthermore, ideals and filters are usually required to be directed (or downward directed). Also, the term "filter map" could possibly refer to morphisms in the category of filters. Perhaps the term "Alexandrov closed" (or "Alexandrov open" depending on whether you want you lower sets to be open or closed) would be better.

Comment: Posets are used extensively in forcing, including many detailed morphism types (and to this extent I could be considered a "poset person"), but this particular notion does not arise significantly in any forcing context to my knowledge. In particular, every poset is forcing equivalent to a poset with no such maps in either direction. And furthermore, we won't generally find such maps from a poset to its Boolean completion, although the projection map from a large forcing notion to a complete subalgebra will have the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one name for this is a [simulation](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simulation).

Comment: thanks for this.  I will wait to see if poset people have a different name before accepting.