# terminology: monotone maps of posets such that the image of a lower set is a lower set

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, terminology, order-theory, posets

How are called in combinatorics

> monotone maps of partially ordered sets such that the image of a lower set is a lower set, i.e. closed (or open) maps of finite topologies? Is there a classification of such maps?

More precisely, I am interested in maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of preorders such that
(i) $x\leq y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$ 
(ii) $x\leq f(y)$ implies there is $x'\leq y$ such that $x=f(x')$.

Is there a classification of such maps between finite preorders? 
Is there a name for them?

The motivation for the question is that these are equivalent
to closed maps of finite topological spaces.

Update: *p-morphism* is a name for these kind of maps in the theory of Kripke frames and modal logics (thanks to Emil Jeřábek). *Esakia morphism* and Esakia spaces is a name for something similar in the theory of Heyting algebras, but Esakia spaces are usually infinite.

Comment: Considered as maps of the upside-down Kripke frames $(X,\ge)\to(Y,\ge)$, such maps $f$ are exactly the p-morphisms (aka bounded morphisms). That’s likely not how order theorists would call them.

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137172/terminology-question-for-poset-maps; I'd still like an answer

Comment: ... from a poset person

Comment: @Emil: thanks! is there a classification or theory of p-morphisms between finite Kripke frames?